# Visual Studio freezing when debugging

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-2013, freeze

Title says it all.  I've searched through a considerable amount of threads only to find nothing.  Specifically, as soon as I run the program I get a loading symbol and then nothing.   If you try to click off of visual studio the rest of my programs run fine (including other instances of VS) leaving the program frozen.  I've tried resetting all of the settings as well as uninstalling/reinstalling new versions (currently running Ultimate 2013).  It should be noted that this error began occurring today but only with newly created projects.  It runs all of my older projects fine but if I create a new project and dump some code (Or in my case, literally make a main method printing "Hello World"), it freezes.  However, if I press "Start without debugging", it breaks with a "error LNK1168 cannot open  for writing.

Comment: "Cannot open for writing" sounds as if you have another copy of the program open, locking the executable file.  Close that and try again.

Comment: Wow, just fixed it.  It was my virus protection.  So glad that that was the last thing I decided to check.

Comment: Well, buggy virus-protection is still common enough, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Check your virus protection before anything else! It will save you a lot of time.